# Big O Recursion with a Case Statement

Tags: java, big-o

I have this program which uses a case statement to switch from printing the array backward to printing it forwards mid recursion. If I were to write this iteratively, it would be one for loop with conditional logic (which can be ignored); thus, the Big O would be O(n). I would assume the same logic holds true for the recursive program as well, correct?

```
    public static int recursion(int i, int j, String swap) {
        int[] testList = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21};
        if (j == 10) {
            return testList[10];
        }
        if (i == 10 ) {
            swap = "Yes";
        }

        switch (swap) {
            case "No":
                System.out.print(testList[i] + " ");
                i -= 1;
                break;
            case "Yes":
                System.out.print(testList[j] + " ");
                j += 1;
                break;
        }
        return recursion(i, j, swap);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String swap = "No";
        int i = 20;
        int j = 0;
        System.out.println(recursion(i, j, swap) + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `swap` should really be a boolean, not a string.

Comment: Yes, it's still O(n). In general: Take the worst case. Now if you must visit every element of the array (length = n) once to complete the algorithm, it's O(n). It doesn't matter if it's a for-loop or recursion.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I initially tried with a boolean value, but I got an error that that wasn't allowed. Perhaps I was implementing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the code as follows to calculate its time complexity

```java
 public static void recursion(int[] testList, int i) { // O(n)
        int len = testList.length; // O(1)

        if(i >= len) return; // O(1)

        int idx = i <= len / 2 ? len - 1 - i: i - len / 2; // O(1)
        System.out.print(testList[idx] + " "); // O(1)

        recursion(testList, i + 1); // O(n - 1)
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] testList = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21};
        recursion(testList, 0);
    }
```

If we create a recurrence relation than we can find its time complexity

```
T(n) = T(n - 1) + C (some constant time) (0 <= n < length)
T(n) = 1 (for n >= length)
```

We can simplify the equation

```
T(n) = T(n - 2) + 2C
     = T(n - 3) + 3C
     .
     .
     = T(n - (n - 1)) + (n - 1)C
     = T(1) + (n - 1)C
     = 1 + (n - 1)C
```

Which gives T(n) = O(n)

Comment: Thanks; I'll parse though this math. I understand at the basic level the theory and logic behind Big O notation, but I'm still learning to understand how to calculate the maths (it's been 20+ years since I took a math class).